# Ruby on Rails: writing a migration to move a column to another table, merge duplicates, then match IDs

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I'm stuck on writing this migration.

Currently I have a buildings table. It lists the building's city as a column.

(There are duplicate cities names in the city column.)

```
  create_table "building", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "city"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I have now created a city model, that `has_many :buildings`.

The buildings now `belongs_to :city`.

I have added a new column `city_id` to buildings for the `belongs_to` association.

```
  create_table "city", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
  add_index "city", ["name"], name: "index_cities_on_name", unique: true
```

I am trying to write migrations that will do the following:

**1. Copy the "city" column from the buildings table to the "name" column in the cities table.**

**2. Merge all duplicated cities in the cities name column**

**3. Match the "city_id" column in the buildings table to the correct city**

But I am absolutely stuck... I've been flipping through the ActiveRecords documentations for an hour now and I'm still not quite sure what to do. Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: As gotva suggests, create a rake task, the migration should only alter table structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: as for me I am against writing SQL query to update data in tables in migrations. I prefer to use rake tasks for this. You can place code below where you would like.

1st. write (and run) a migration with `cities` table

2nd. perform this code in rake task or migration

```
Building.all.each do |building|
  city = City.find_or_create(name: building.city) # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by
  building.city_id = city.id
  building.save!
end
```

3rd. write migration which remove column `buildings.city`

Some notes:

1. if you have a lot of buildings (for example 10000+ records) you can use `find_each` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each
2. I prefer to use `save!` to be sure that I will notice that some building can not be saved - I can recheck this item manually
3. do not add reference to Building `belongs_to :city` before 2nd step, because I am not sure what column Rails will try to find `buildings.city` (old city name) or object `city` (it will nil because `city_id` is nill at this moment)

Comment: This is great! Is it bad practice to be putting the 2nd step in a migration? (I've never worked with rake tasks but perhaps it's time to start)

Comment: Yes it is. Migration must go from start to end without errors. You can place this code in migration. Later you add to city required field `country` (or `country_id`) as a result your migration will be broken (`City.find_or_create(name: building.city)` - will not create a record!). Modifying migration is very BAD thing! You can change your rake task as you want or even just remove it - because this action (migrating `city_id`) is a uniq operation

Comment: Okay that makes so much sense! thank you. When I try to run this through a rake task, it gives me: rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Building

Comment: Silly me. Forgot to add the environment!

Comment: So this is a really dicey solution - it highlights the kind of forward compatibility issues that arise when referencing ActiveRecord models in migrations.  Just note #3 ('I am not sure what column...') gives me the chills.  Putting the code in a rake task is better than directly referencing AR models in the migration itself, but only because you can remove the code from the Rake task immediately after running this on prod.  But that assumes this migration will and can only be run once, and will not be needed afterwards.  A bad practice, and totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't do the data migration in ActiveRecord.  There are forward compatibility issues with directly referencing ActiveRecord model classes in migrations.  As a general rule I try and avoid it.  So I'd fall back to SQL.

Not sure what DB you're using, but something like this should work for MySQL:

```
execute("INSERT INTO cities(name, created_at, updated_at) SELECT DISTINCT city, NOW(), NOW() FROM buildings;")
execute("UPDATE buildings SET buildings.city_id = (SELECT city_id FROM cities where cities.name = buildings.name);")
```

The first statement initializes the cities table with no duplicates, while the second statement sets the city_id column on buildings.

Similar statements (potentially with slightly different syntax) will work for other databases.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. No wonder why I couldn't find any info on writing migrations for this. I'm using SQLite3 on development and PostGreSQL on production so I'll give this a try!

Comment: it is very bad practise to use different DB in your environments! You can have correct code in dev env and broken production

Comment: I concur with @gotva - very bad idea to use different dbs in development and production.  It's easy enough to set up a local Postgres environment - I'd encourage you to do so.